# sending the same information to different views cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a problem here with cakePHP. I have 4 .ctp view pages that I want to send information to from my controller. These are not static pages, they are actually dynamic pages with user forms where the user can enter informations. I have a situation where I have to send the same array to the 4 different views (because part of each view needs that array to display the same information, in order words, I want to display the same information on 4 different views). I know that normally I'm supposed to have 1 view per controller actions, but this time I don't want to create 4 similar actions for each of my views (because like I said, all I'm doing is sending an array to each of my 4 view files). How do I go about doing this without creating 4 repetitive actions in my controller for my 4 view files. I hope it's clear enough what I'm trying to do here.

thank you

Comment: How would you be displaying those views? Is this a case where the action is identical, but based on some variable a slightly altered view should be used? Or are the actions completely different, but the views have some common element?

Comment: The actions are identical and the views are different. Basically, I'm sending the same array which will be display on different parts of each view

Comment: If I got you right, may be you should see this link http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1081/Elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use one action in the controller and `render` different views based on some logic:

```
public function my_action() {
    $this->set('myVar1', ...);
    $this->set('myVar2', ...);
    $this->set('myVar3', ...);

    if (/* something */) {
        $this->render('foo'); // renders my_controller/foo.ctp
    } else if (/* or other */) {
        $this->render('bar');
    } ...
}
```